# Generating a random comma separated list of product ID's then summing their value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In column A I have a product ID, in column B the product price.

I want to take a random number of product ID's (lets say between 1 and 5), add them to a cell in a comma separated format, then in another cell sum the product prices of those products.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any sample data to work with and your own attempt to solving your issue would also be greatly appreciated. Currently your question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had Prod ID in column A and price in column B, you could make a random generator of X products (Let's say in E2) like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN( ", ", 1, INDEX( A2:A11, RANDARRAY(5,1,1,10,1) ) )
```

where 5 is the number of elements you want and 10 is the count of all products and A2:A11 is the list of product IDs.

Then in let's say E4, you could calculate the sum of the randomly chosen prices with :

```
=SUM( XLOOKUP( FILTERXML( "<m><s>" & SUBSTITUTE( E2, ", ", "</s><s>" ) & "</s></m>", "//s" ), $A$2:$A$11,$B$2:$B$11,,0) )
```

where A2:A11 are the prod id's and B2:B11 are the prices.

[image]

Comment: That works a treat, thank you. Just one final question, if I wanted to set a minimum value in E4, how could I go about doing that?

Comment: Hi - @user8358204 - cool. Well, you could wrap the formula in E4 in a MAX. Like this '=MAX( 20, SUM( XLOOKUP( FILTERXML( "<m><s>" & SUBSTITUTE( E2, ", ", "</s><s>" ) & "</s></m>", "//s" ), $A$2:$A$11,$B$2:$B$11,,0) ))'. This would create a min of 20. Also, if you don't want any repeats of products, give a shout. The randomization formula would need to be changed.

Comment: Thanks again, that's very kind of you.